# Use Carbon Copy Cloner with existing backup

Tags: backup, incremental-backup

I want to use Carbon Copy Cloner to take over from an existing backup solution. I have an external disk with 1.8TB of data on it replicated/backed up from a folder my local drive.

However in order to benefit from the incremental functionality of CCC, it seems to want to do a full backup of all this data itself. Is there any way to just make it comare with the up to data folder on the backup drive and do an incremental update from there?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after doing some further tests and investigations, I discovered an inconsistency in my setup.

Given a source and destination file with the same/similar contents, CCC will still only update those files which are new/modified in the source folder.

It doesn't need to run it's own backup before it can compare correctly.